# Экземпляр вариадик шаблона класса "функтора"

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Имеется следующая задача: необходимо описать шаблон класс "функция", который будет вызывать какую-то функцию, при этом у функции может или не может быть переменное число аргументов.

Известно, что внутри класса хранится адрес этой функции.

Это нужно, чтобы унифицировать вызов функций с несколькими параметрами. При этом сами функции находятся где-то в памяти приложений и, естественно, исходного кода этих функций у меня нет. Поскольку такой способ передачи аргументов (`...`) возможен только при `_cdecl`, вот я и подумал, что будет достаточно одной функции, которая поместит аргументы в стек и передаст управление на тот адрес, который я укажу. Если у меня будет шаблон, способный корректно обрабатывать указатели на `printf` и `sprintf`, значит, я смогу с помощью этого шаблона обработать любую функцию с переменным числом аргументов.

Пример 1 (возможно, некорректный):

```
// Какой-то конструктор получающий адрес, или любая 
// другая конструкция, позволяющая передать адрес этой функции.
Function<int, const char*, ...> fnc(0x12345678);

// Вызов функции, которая находится по адресу 0x12345678
int result = fnc.call("blablabla", arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

Пример 2. Был проверен на функциях, принимающих конечное количество аргументов. Всё работает, но меня интересует вышеописанная ситуация, когда у функции может быть переменное число аргументов(как у `printf` или `sprintf`):

```
//Нерабочий код
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
template<typename Signature>
std::function<Signature> make_function1(unsigned int* p) {
  return [p](auto... a) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Signature*>(p)(a...);
  };
}
template<typename R, typename... A>
std::function<R(A...)> make_function2(unsigned int* p) {
  return [p](A... a) {
    return reinterpret_cast<R(*)(A...)>(p)(a...);
  };
}
int main()
{
  printf("printf test: %s\n", "trololo");
  std::function<int(const char*, ...)> fnc1 = make_function1<int(const char*, ...)>((unsigned int*)printf);
  std::function<int(const char*, ...)> fnc2 = make_function2<int, const char*, ...>((unsigned int*)printf);
  fnc1("fnc1 test: %d\n", 1); //Ошибка, не определен operator()
  fnc2("fnc2 test: %d\n", 2); //Ошибка, не определён operator()
  return 0;
}
```

// UPD:

То, о чём я вас попросил - не предоставляется возможным. Более подробно об этом написано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370396/why-cant-stdfunction-bind-to-c-style-variadic-functions
Найдено решение в стиле С, без шаблонов:

```
#include <cstdio>
#define CDECL_FUNCTION( Name, Address, RetType, ... ) \
RetType(*Name)(__VA_ARGS__, ...) = (RetType(*)(__VA_ARGS__, ...))Address;
int main()
{ 
  printf("printf test: %s\n", "trololo");
  CDECL_FUNCTION(fnc, printf, int, const char* fmt);
  CDECL_FUNCTION(fnc2, snprintf, int, const char* buffer, int bufLen, const char* format);
  char buffer[256];
  fnc2(buffer, 256, "testing, %s, %d\n", "hey:its", 10);
  fnc("%s", buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните для чего это требуется

Comment: @Abyx Что за "вариадик". Было же по-русски написано.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Я отмечу после того, как проверю - подходит мне этот вариатн, или нет. Пока нет влзможности.

Comment: @Cerbo Это нужно, чтобы унифицировать вызов функций с несколькими параметрами. При этом сами функции находятся где-то в памяти приложений и, естественно, исходного кода этих функций у меня нет. Поскольку такой способ передачи аргументов (...) возможен только при _cdecl, вот я и подумал, что будет достаточно одной функции, которая поместит аргументы в стек и передаст управление на тот адрес, который я укажу. Если у меня будет шаблон, способный корректно обрабатывать указатели на printf и sprintf, значит, я смогу с помощью этого шаблона обработать любую функцию с переменным числом аргументов.

Comment: @T-Max Вы здесь новенький, поэтому извините, но я немного поясню вам местные порядки. Комментарии второстепенны, их пишут под вопросом и ответами не для критики, а для уточнения и обсуждения. Вы, как автор вопроса, должны не отвечать коментариями, а править вопрос если вас просят уточнить что-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите обычный `std::function`

```
template<typename Signature>
std::function<Signature> make_function(DWORD_PTR p) {
  return [p](auto... a){
    return reinterpret_cast<Signature*>(p)(a...);
  };
}

std::function<int(float)> fnc = make_function<int(float)>(0x12345678);
```

Ну или если компилятор не умеет шаблонные лямбда-выражения, тогда

```
template<typename R, typename... A>
std::function<R(A...)> make_function(DWORD_PTR p) {
  return [p](A... a){
    return reinterpret_cast<R(*)(A...)>(p)(a...);
  };
}

std::function<int(float)> fnc = make_function<int, float>(0x12345678);
```